# Mapping to object in Spring MVC REST

Tags: xml, spring, rest, spring-mvc

so I'm fairly new to Spring MVC and have been building an application that hosts + uses several APIs, most of it is working fine, but I ran into a wall now.

For some reason, the attributes from the xml don't get mapped into the object. I haven't had this problem with JSONs, but unfortunately in this case I'm on the receiving end and I cannot change the format of the request.
The request payload is something like:

```
<xml>
 <ToUserName> <![CDATA[toUser]]> </ToUserName>
 <FromUserName> <![CDATA[fromUser]]> </FromUserName> 
 <CreateTime> 1348831860 </CreateTime>
 <MsgType> <![CDATA[text]]> </MsgType>
 <Content><![CDATA[this is a test]]></Content>
 <MsgId>1234567890123456</MsgId>
</xml>
```

I'm trying to map it onto a class that has these + many more attributes, but those can remain null when not needed.
Now my controller method is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/msg", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/xml", produces = "application/xml")
    @ResponseBody
    public void receive(@RequestBody ReceivedMessage msg) {
        //TODO: do something with the message here... for now just dump into log
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
```

Seems like it should work, right?
Well, output goes like

```
ReceivedMessage{toUserName=null, fromUserName=null, createTime=null, msgType=null, msgId=null, medes=null, content=null, picUrl=null, format=null, thumbMediaId=null, location_X=null, location_Y=null, label=null, scale=null, title=null, description=null, url=null, recognition=null, event=null, eventKey=null, ticket=null, latitude=null, longitude=null, precision=null}
```

As you can see, all of the attributes are null, even the ones provided in the payload...

I'm assuming it might have something to do with the way the payload is structured, but as I said, I can't change that.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: fixed typo in title...
EDIT2: further info... relevant part of servlet config:

```
<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
    <bean id="xmlConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter"/>
    <bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
                <ref bean="xmlConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

EDIT3: ReceivedMessage (getters and setters omitted):

```
public class ReceivedMessage{
    //common
    private String toUserName;
    private String fromUserName;
    private Long createTime;
    private String msgType;

    private Long msgId;

    private String medes;

    //text
    private String content;
    //image
    private String picUrl;
    //voice + speech recognition
    private String format;
    //video
    private String thumbMediaId;
    //location
    private Double location_X;
    private Double location_Y;
    private String label;
    private Double scale;
    //link
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String url;
    //speech recognition
    private String recognition;
    //event + QR code scan + location incident + menu event
    private String event;
    //QR code scan + menu event
    private String eventKey;
    //QR code scan
    private String ticket;
    //location incident
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
    private Double precision;

    public ReceivedMessage() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you want to convert XML to java object and vice versa, you need to use JAXB for marshalling and unmarshalling. There are ready made message converters like Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter  in spring which could help.

Comment: Please share the contents of `ReceivedMessage` class.

Comment: @Mithun class added, currently looking into Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` is used to convert Java objects to/from XML. The message conversion works if it satisfies below conditions:

- This converter is pre-enabled, if JAXB2 is present on the classpath.
- The java class should have the xml to java binding details

Example:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
    String name;
    int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: was throwing exception for unknown element before adding (name = "xml") to the XmlRootElement annotation, now it goes ok but with the same result as in the beginning, all nulls

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem. Could you please re-name the tags to be same as the variable names in the java class. Eg: ToUserName **to** toUserName.

Comment: well since I cant change the xml input (its from 3rd party API), I decided to remove getters/setters, make vars public and rename them to start with capital letter. That works.
Its not ideal as it kinda breaks encapsulation and naming conventions, but given the situation it seems to be necessary.
Thanks for the help